# I used "Cordova-open-native-settings" in ionic v1 but not work

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I want to open Wi-Fi setting with [Cordova-open-native-settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311855/i-used-cordova-open-native-settings-in-ionic-v1-buy-not-work) in ionic v1, but not work.

```
if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.settings) {
  console.log('openNativeSettingsTest is active');
  window.cordova.plugins.settings.open("wifi", function() {
          console.log('opened settings');
      },
      function () {
          console.log('failed to open settings');
      }
  );
```

}

suggest me, please.

thanks,

ps. sorry for my English.

Comment: which is not work . is it Cordova-open-native-settings ?

Comment: Plugins is worked, but I can not open wifi setting.